# Java Integer.parseInt wants to parse words that are already gone

Tags: java

for a Java beginner tutorial for a TicTacToe game I'm writing a method that's giving me an exception.
I want to ask if somebody may kindly help me to fix this and explain why this happend?

The description for the task is:

User input contains 2 positive integers separated by a white space.
If user types in words an error message must tell the user to use numbers, if numbers are negative or our of range the message tells to use numbers 1-3.

I was testing this by entering the two words "one" and "two", the code correctly says to enter numbers.
When I now enter the integers "1" and "2" the method runs to it's end but then crashes an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "one"
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
at Scratch.getValidCoordinates(scratch_3.java:21)
at Scratch.main(scratch_3.java:6) 




import java.util.Scanner;

class Scratch {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getValidCoordinates();
}

public static int[] getValidCoordinates() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the coordinates: ");
    String[] coordinates = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");

    if (!coordinates[0].matches("(-|\\+)?\\d+") || !coordinates[1].matches("(-|\\+)?\\d+")) {
        System.out.println("You should enter numbers!");
        getValidCoordinates();
    }

    int[] numCoordinates = {Integer.parseInt(coordinates[0]), 
Integer.parseInt(coordinates[1])};

    if (numCoordinates[0] > 3 || numCoordinates[0] < 1 || numCoordinates[1] > 3 || 
numCoordinates[1] < 1) {
        System.out.println("Coordinates should be from 1 to 3!");
        getValidCoordinates();
    }

    return numCoordinates;
 }
}
```

Comment: Don't recurse. Use an infinite loop and `continue;`

Comment: And *if* you do recurse, do something with the returned array (even just re-return it).

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca could you please specify what you mean be re-returning?

Comment: Just calling `getValidCoordinates` you lose whatever the recursive call returns, so you should `return getValidCoordinates();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exception happens when your recursion returns to the original flow of execution. Either return the array you receive from recursion, or change to an infinite loop and `continue` instead of recursing. Like,

```
public static int[] getValidCoordinates() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the coordinates: ");
    String[] coordinates = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");

    if (!coordinates[0].matches("(-|\\+)?\\d+")
            || !coordinates[1].matches("(-|\\+)?\\d+")) {
        System.out.println("You should enter numbers!");
        return getValidCoordinates();
    }

    int[] numCoordinates = { Integer.parseInt(coordinates[0]),
            Integer.parseInt(coordinates[1])
    };

    if (numCoordinates[0] > 3 || numCoordinates[0] < 1
            || numCoordinates[1] > 3 || numCoordinates[1] < 1) {
        System.out.println("Coordinates should be from 1 to 3!");
        return getValidCoordinates();
    }

    return numCoordinates;
}
```

Or with an infinite loop like

```
public static int[] getValidCoordinates() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter the coordinates: ");
        String[] coordinates = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");

        if (!coordinates[0].matches("(-|\\+)?\\d+")
                    || !coordinates[1].matches("(-|\\+)?\\d+")) {
            System.out.println("You should enter numbers!");
            continue;
        }

        int[] numCoordinates = { Integer.parseInt(coordinates[0]), 
            Integer.parseInt(coordinates[1])
        };

        if (numCoordinates[0] > 3 || numCoordinates[0] < 1
                    || numCoordinates[1] > 3 || numCoordinates[1] < 1) {
            System.out.println("Coordinates should be from 1 to 3!");
            continue;
        }

        return numCoordinates;
    }
}
```

To further aid your understanding, consider the following trivial program.

```
static int recurse(int a) {
    try {
        throw new Exception("A " + a);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (a < 10) {
        recurse(a + 1);
    }
    try {
        throw new Exception("B " + a);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    recurse(1);
}
```

Note that you can clearly see the stackframe grow (and shrink) as the function recursively counts up to `10` (and then down to `1`).

Comment: Thank you.
So return getValidCoordinates(); instead of only getValidCoordinates(); truly "resets" everything inside the method?

Comment: No. It causes program flow to return to the caller. Instead of proceeding with the method.

Comment: Fritsch could you please explain this a little simpler? :)

Comment: The *simplest* explanation is "recursion". The original execution ***continues*** when the stackframe is unwound by the recursive call returning. Your original code drops the result of the recursive call.

Comment: Why is "one" not printed when I place a print statement to print coordinates in my original code right before the return?
I mean, where is the "one" stored in my code? What variable do I have to print to see where "one" is?

Comment: That would be the stackframe. Where the value is pushed when you recurse into the new execution of `getValidCoordinates`. And no, you can't directly see it. It's on the stack. You **can** see where you are on the stack by throwing an exception and printing the stacktrace. [`Throwable.printStackTrace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace())

Comment: Using this is beyond my novice understanding, but I think I understand the principle behind your explanation :)
Thank you very much for taking time to help me here :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's debug your code! But let me simplify it with pseudocode:

```java
void main() {
  coordinates();
}

int[] coordinates() {
  coordinates = nextLine().split(" ");
  if(!coordinates.matches("(-|\\+)?\\d+")) {
    print("Only numbers are allowed");
    coordinates();
  }

  numberCoordinates = coordinates.toInt();
  if(coordinates.bounds()) {
    print("Out of bounds");
    coordinates();
  }

  return numberCoordinates;
}
```

Let's "run" it:

- We are entering `one two`
- It splits and now `coordinates = {"one", "two"}`
- But it doesn't match the regex, calling another `coordinates()` function
- We are entering `1 2`
- It splits and matches correctly
- But, we are coming back to a outer `coordinates()` function and it continues
- `coordinates[0]` in outer `coordinates()` function is still `one`
- Function is not stopped even if validation failed and your `Integer.parseInt` also fails

I've drawed a scheme for you :)
[image]

That's it! Rewrite your function with `while` - when your validation fails, just use `continue` keyword and your function will request a new line!

Comment: Thank you for this cool scheme! :)

I see... 
Well, I thought calling the method again will "reset" everything.
At least I was thinking so, because I checked the values of String coordinates[] and int numCoordinates[] with a print statement and I couldn't find "one" anywhere

Comment: @KabraxisLuvos, it's ok, we're all making mistakes sometimes. Programming is a misterious forest :P If you found my answer useful, please, don't forget to mark it as 'right'! Thanks! :) (But, if you have any question, ask here! :P)

Comment: why isn't print numberCoordinates or coordinates print showing "one" if I place it before my return statement? :)

Comment: @KabraxisLuvos because "one" is not a number :) When you pass non-numeric values into console, `return` statement is never reached :(